# Handle cross-domain AJAX POST request in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, .htaccess

I have next situation:

- I have WP plugin with simple API.
- this plugin can be installed to the WP instance on different hosting with different folders structure (WPEngine for example.) and without ability to edit .htaccess
- there is a client on another domain, which should send via AJAX scope of data to my plugin and get calculated data (Cross-Domain request);

Plugin - it's my product.

AJAX client - another users, who will use my "calculator".

**So questions:**

- how should I catch this request in my plugin?
- which URL should AJAX client to use for access to my API? I can't to use URL with full path to the plugin and file with handler.
- will be super to understand how should AJAX request method look.

Comment: We won't be able to help if we don't know the structure of your plugin and/or code. This is far too general of a question(s).

Comment: This plugin consists of many files and I can't to share them all. I'll try explain  more detailed: 

- plugin it's a calculator of payments relatively from many parameters. It's implemented as separate WP plugin which should work on different hostings (plugin can be sold out to other users);

- client - it's Facebook bot, which collects params from questionnaire
in chat, sends data to the calculator and then gets calculated results and additional links.


I don't have  an access to Facebook bot. My side - it's a plugin. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This method in insecure. 
You should be using the WP rest API for accepting cross-domain requests. 
Also, you should be adding auth 1.0 that comes shipped with the WP rest API. 
Here is a link showing you how to add your own endpoint to the rest api 
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

And here is link showing you how to secure your api with authentication with auth 1.0.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-oauth1/

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

You need to create a function in PHP to make the API call to your server and add it to the [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) and [wp_ajax_nopriv](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) hooks.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_ajax_function', 'your_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_ajax_function', 'your_ajax_function' );
function your_ajax_function() {
    $url = 'http://www.google.com'; // url to your rest API
    if ( isset( $_POST['data'] ) ) {
        $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array( 'data' => $_POST['data'] ) );
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            echo $response->get_error_message();
            exit;
        }
        else {
            wp_send_json( $response );
        }
    }
}
```

To make sure you have access to the correct ajax path, [localize the path for ajax for use in javascript](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'localize_ajax' );
function localize_ajax() {
    wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}
```

**Note:** change `jquery` to your javascript file and/or make sure you create your function once `jquery` has been enqueued on the page.

Next, create your function in javascript that calls your ajax function passing the user value in the `data` field and attach it to some event listener:

```
function yourFunction() {
  jQuery.ajax( {
    method: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
      'action' : 'your_ajax_function',
      'data' : 'test'
    },
    success: function( response ) {
      // do what you want with your response
      console.log( response );
    }
  });
}
```

This will return back the response from your API call, so use `response` to populate your results in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, but there is one restriction - AJAX POST request will send from another domain, so I can't localize path (ajaxurl) to JS file.

Comment: The localized path is for the user's WP install where presumably your own plugin files exist. If you are creating a WP plugin then you should be able to localize the ajax path, and make a call to an ajax function using WP. That will bypass the limitations of cross-domain requests using ajax alone to accomplish this.